# Libgdx tic tac toe game

Tags: java, input, libgdx

```
public class CrossAndCircles extends ApplicationAdapter{

    OrthographicCamera camera;
    SpriteBatch batch;
    ShapeRenderer renderer;
    Array<Rectangle> array;
    Vector3 touchPos;
    int turn, cellSize, touchCount;
    float tempX, tempY;



    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        renderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, 480, 480);


        touchCount = 0;

        cellSize = 480/3-5;
        array = new Array<Rectangle>();

        //cell's coordinates
        Rectangle oneOne = new Rectangle(0, 0 ,cellSize, cellSize);
        Rectangle oneTwo = new Rectangle(0, cellSize+5, cellSize, cellSize);
        Rectangle oneThree = new Rectangle(0, 480-cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
        Rectangle twoOne = new Rectangle(cellSize+5, 0 , cellSize, cellSize);
        Rectangle twoTwo = new Rectangle(cellSize+5, cellSize+5, cellSize, cellSize);
        Rectangle twoThree = new Rectangle(cellSize+10, 480-cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
        Rectangle threeOne = new Rectangle(480-cellSize, 0 , cellSize, cellSize);
        Rectangle threeTwo = new Rectangle (480-cellSize, cellSize+5, cellSize, cellSize);
        Rectangle threeThree = new Rectangle(480-cellSize, 480-cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
        array.add(oneOne); array.add(oneTwo); array.add(oneThree); array.add(twoOne);
        array.add(twoTwo); array.add(twoThree); array.add(threeOne); array.add(threeTwo); array.add(threeThree);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        camera.update();
        //our field
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        renderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
        renderer.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        renderer.rect(480/3-5, 0, 10, 480);
        renderer.rect(480/3*2-5, 0, 10, 480);
        renderer.rect(0, 480 / 3 - 10, 480, 10);
        renderer.rect(0, 480 / 3 * 2 - 10, 480, 10);
        renderer.end();

        //if user touch a rectangle draw a circle or a cross
        if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
            for (Rectangle rect:array) {
                if (rect.contains(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY())) {
                    tempX = rect.x;
                    tempY = rect.y;
                    break;
                    }}
            touchCount++;
        }

        if (touchCount>0 && touchCount<=9){
            renderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
            renderer.rect(tempX+20,tempY+20,0, 0, 10, cellSize, 1, 1, -45);
            renderer.end();}

    }

    public void dispose(){super.dispose(); renderer.dispose();}

}
```

Help me with my Tic tac toe game. I've still added only one stick but it appears only twice, and when I'm clicking to the upper cells it appears in lowers. And I don't know why the first stick is not saved, it just change it's place. What's wrong in my logic?

Answer (score 1):

there is difference in touch and screen coordinates, 
refer :
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Coordinate-systems

Comment: link only answers are discouraged as that page will likely change over time. please quote the relevant portion